# Async Await not working some places in staging schema afer upgrading from 0.67.4 to 0.71.14 version with hermes

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-hermes

1. I have upgraded my React Native project from 0.67.4 to 0.71.14.
2. Async Await not working properly in some places of code.

- ex: async someFunction() {
  await NetInfo.fetch()
  }

3. in debug mode it works properly but when generating a build with staging schema it not works. (Has anyone faced this type of issue?)

**Here I don't have proper reproducible steps as it working fine in the debug schema not sure what happening in the staging schema.**

1. I have tried converting from async to await to .then and .catch.
2. but I have these issues in other places too. converting the code in all places is not possible as we have some other dependencies
3. not sure why it not working only with staging schema builds.